# Did you forget to register or load this tag? Using Django

Tags: html, css, django, if-statement

I don't get it, If I remove the last `<li>` I'm not getting this error, here's my HTML,
I know I'm not closing a "if" tag correctly or something, the only solution for me is to remove the last last `<li>`

```
{% if request.get_full_path != "/addAssest/" and request.user.is_authenticated
%}
<div class="sidebar" style="height: 35%">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard-django"
        class="simple-text logo-mini"
      >
        CC
      </a>
      <a
        target="_blank"
        href="https://www.creative-tim.com/product/black-dashboard-django"
        class="simple-text logo-normal"
      >
        Crypto Castle
      </a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="{% if 'index' in segment %} active {% endif %}">
        <a href="/">
          <i class="tim-icons icon-chart-pie-36"></i>
          <p>Dashboard</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="{% if 'page-user' in segment %} active {% endif %}">
        <a href="{% url 'profilePage' %}">
          <i class="tim-icons icon-single-02"></i>
          <p>User Profile</p>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="{% if 'logout' in segment %} active {% endif %}">
        <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">
          <i class="tim-icons icon-user-run"></i>
          <p>Logout</p>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is that `%}` on a new line? A template tag must be on one single line, the parser does not look for linebreaks when looking for template tags.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat its not a new line, as soon as i save it, it goes down like that, but it worked with that if i remove the last <li>

Comment: check my answer, your linting might cause force the new line

Comment: "_as soon as i save it, it goes down like that_", check your editor / IDE settings, looks like it is formatting your code on file save.

Comment: What about `'logout'` itself ?  if it works while removing that part and that it looks like there's no typo .. and that your template tags do stand on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Django template does not support multiline tags and tag escape tags as stated in this [Ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8652)

You should edit your code :

```
    {% if request.get_full_path != "/addAssest/" and request.user.is_authenticated
%}
```

to

```
{% if request.get_full_path != "/addAssest/" and request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Note that most HTML linter will try to break your template tag so it is best to deactivate it

Comment: This is the fix, i disabled an addon to make HTML prettier, thanks my main man

Comment: Please accept my answer so it could help other, thanks.

Comment: I cant, i dont have enough rep